# How can I submit a DOM table to php?

Tags: dom

I have a <table> in a web page that I populate using JavaScript code like this:

```
var cellBarcode = row.insertCell(1);
var textNode = document.createTextNode(barcode);
cellBarcode.appendChild(textNode);
var cellItemName = row.insertCell(2);
var textNode = document.createTextNode(itemName);
cellItemName.appendChild(textNode);
```

I need to save its data to my database... So I need to know how I can submit it to php... Is it possible...? If yes, please provide some sample codes that are easy to understand for a beginner like me... thanks...

Comment: What's a DOM table for you? I presume it's not an instance of the DOMElement class or otherwise you'd not be talking about "passing to PHP". If it's a JavaScript question, feel free to edit your question and add such tag together with further details (such as some code).

Comment: This is how I add rows and columns to my table

var cellBarcode = row.insertCell(1);
var textNode = document.createTextNode(barcode);
 cellBarcode.appendChild(textNode);
 
var cellItemName = row.insertCell(2);
var textNode = document.createTextNode(itemName);
cellItemName.appendChild(textNode);

Is it possible to submit those values to php?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can submit this information to a server-side script, but not without extra JavaScript code.

The extra JavaScript code would collect the information in the table (either from the DOM you've built, or by accessing the same data you used when building the table) into a string, which can then be sent to the server using one of standard ways.

Since you've used the term "submit", I'm assuming you want to send the table's data as part of an HTML <form> submission, you can put the generated string in an <input type="hidden"> element.